# URL rewrite using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I need a URL like

```
mydomain.com/myname/?action=post&data=10
```

Here in a single PHP page (`user.php`), I need all `myname`, `post` and `10` as GET method variables. How can I get it using `.htaccess`?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122097/apache-mod-rewrite-primers

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myname/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```